# Close question because image is sideways

Tags: discussion

On multiple occasions while browsing through the close votes queue, I've come across "do my homework for me!!!" questions that have a scanned image from a textbook where the the image is sideways. These are much worse than are the typical "do my homework for me, please" kinds of questions. At least they said "please". Many of them have even have done a bit of work, but then got lost.

I'm not ranting about those questions. I'm ranting about the questions with sideways images. IMHO, a very special category is needed for people who post a sideways image scanned from a textbook and haven't shown a spot of work. Humiliation would be a good start.

Just saying.

Comment: True story: before I was a moderator, I voted to close a question because it contained too many capital letters, with a link to the [crackpot index](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html). That comment got deleted, which was probably a good thing.  As a moderator, I think that humiliation is a poor community-management strategy.

Comment: "Image is sideways" as a reason to close is humiliation, but it also tells the questioner what to do.

Comment: Since nobody has said it yet: humiliation is *never* appropriate on this site. If you think the OP is being egregiously lazy, then vote to close, downvote, and move on. The only one that loses if you get angry is your liver.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : while I agree humiliation may not be appropriate, instilling some patience might be more constructive: how about an automatic pause of - say - 24 or 48 hours, during which such solve-this-problem-for-me questions can be upvoted or downvoted but not answered?  This would eliminate "urgent" questions without removing the service of clarifying misinterpreted aspects of basic physics.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm pretty sure that something similar has been proposed before as well.

Comment: @KyleKanos  I can see it gets annoying on a recurring basis.  You elders would know better how to best angle this.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Lol, elders. Your profile says you've been here 3 months less than me ;) For reference, here's the [meta post I was talking about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10890/).

Comment: @KyleKanos : I arrived here perchance years ago after I was told  students had posted an assignment from my course on this site.    Clearly they had not found the question anywhere online (I make my own).  As a result I have a particular bias against the "please-help-me-urgently-solve-this-problem" types of questions.

Comment: @KyleKanos You are still elders in terms of rep.  :)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero that feature already exists: its called putting on hold. As I said: vote to close, downvote if appropriate, and move on.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Is that enough to deter http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308833/36194
(which I did NOT make up just to illustrate the point)?  I will defer to you and others: you are doing more for this site than I ever will.

Comment: well I guess the specific post I linked to was just taken down so that voids the first part of my comment (but not the second :)  )

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm fairly OK with the speed at which this site is closing do-my-work-for-me at present, though there are a few of those that get answers when they shouldn't. If you want to help avoid that, then flag to close as soon as you see them, if 3k+ vote to close, and man the review queues, and bring them up in chat if they're particularly bad. To be honest, right now I'm more bothered by on-topic but mundane and boring start-of-term questions, but it's often pretty mean to downvote those.

Answer (score 3):

No, we shouldn't close questions simply because they are images of a textbook/web page/something else.<sup>1</sup> Instead you should either (a) transcribe it (assuming it's legible & you have the time) or (b) leave a comment that such a question (i.e., image of textbook/web page/something) is not usually well-received and leave a link to the [MathJax tutorial](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

<sup>I have found that these types of questions are often lazy "do my homework for me" type questions that do deserve closure, but it's because of that aspect and not the sideways image.</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much agree with this. I'd also probably downvote the question. (Keeping in mind that downvotes can be reversed after the post is edited.)